# how to Move files upward in folder in github

Tags: github, hierarchy

I have the folder called, SpartanDrive-hansol, as you see in the picture, and it contains all the necessary files that I need. But just the folder, SpartanDrive-hansol, is unnecessary, and it causes a problem when I try to merge it with master branch because master branch does not have that folder.

Can anyone help me how to delete the unnecessary hierarchy of the folder? (But I need all the files that are in the folder) Thank you!

[image]

Comment: On your local machine, ensure your current branch is `hansol`, and then move the folder contents out of the folder to the root, then delete the `SpartanDrive-hansol` folder and commit the changes and push it to your remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with the terminal. In the parent directory of the SpartanDrive-hansol folder, run the following command in the terminal:

```
mv SpartanDrive-hansol/* .
```

This will move all contents of the folder to your current folder, which in this case is the parent folder.